# execl in externnotify C code not working in voicemail part of Asterisk

Tags: system, asterisk, voicemail, execl, external-script

I am struggling with this problem. In Asterisk, I need to execute an external script after leaving a voicemail message. For this, I enabled externnotify in voicemail.conf but it was not working. So I searched in C code and found the related code. The command that executes the external script is:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", s, (char *) NULL);
```

in which **s** is `/usr/bin/myscript.sh default 2000 12 8 0 &`.
excel runs in child process successfully but the script `myscript.sh` which is:

```
#!/bin/sh
CONTEXT=$1
EXTEN=$2
NUMVMS=$3
echo "$CONTEXT $EXTEN $NUMVMS" > /home/testfile
```

is not executed. The strange part is I wrote another C file and put the execl command in it and it executes my script successfully. I replaced `execl` with `system` command but no success again. Which part have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i have say you, that voicemail ALREADY have notify functionality and it works ok.

About why your script not work - likly you tested it under root user, while most asterisk running under asterisk user, so you have permission issue on write to your log file.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Actually I changed the owner and group of my script to asterisk. isn't it ok? what should I do?

Comment: you should temporary enable login for asterisk user, login as asterisk, run script,see error. after that ensure you asterisk user have nologin.

Comment: I did what you said, but I didn't see any error. where I should see errors? in the asterisk log file? no error happens in there.

Comment: You should debug script using commandline using asterisk user and see error. If you unsure how asterisk call it, you can use asterisk debug(core set debug 5)

Comment: I have already done all of these suggestions and then posted my question here. I even added some code for debugging purpose inside C file `asterisk.c` which is responsible for this matter. In logger.conf I enabled full log. As I said before, `execl` runs successfully and produces no errors in log file but doesn't execute the script.